# What is the purpose of "__SRCVERSION" function at the end of each C file?

Tags: c

I am working on the source code of a Unix-based kernel. I noticed that the last line of each source code file (.c or .h) is a specific line with the following format:

```
__SRCVERSION( "$URL: ... $ $Rev: 219996 $" )
```

The URL points to the web address of the same file. I'm wondering what does that mean, and what is it actually for? Would it be any problem if I delete this line from all of my source code files?

Comment: How can we possibly answer that question without seeing complete code of your kernel? This `__SRCVERSION` can be anything: maybe it just some compiled string, and maybe it's being used somewhere and hence it's essential.

Comment: That looks like a preprocessor macro, not a function. Find the definition of the macro and take a look at what it expands to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros like this are often used to embed versioning information into binaries when they are compiled.  They can be updated automatically when fetched out of a [source control system with appropriate rules](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html).  Removing them shouldn't cause any harm, but you will lose the benefit of being able to search a binary to identify which versions of your source files were used to compile it.

As @Keith Thompson says below, it may also be possible to configure your build to not embed the information.  Below is an example of the macro definition taken from [here](http://apsc496.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/design_documents/control_system/rtos/bsp-TI-omap3530-src/install/usr/include/sys/srcversion.h) (different systems are likely to have different definitions).  You can see that it uses the `__USESRCVERSION` definition to decide which version of the `__SRCVERSION` macro is used:

```
#ifndef __USESRCVERSION
#define __SRCVERSION(id)
#else /* __USESRCVERSION */

#ifdef __QNXNTO__

#if defined __SRCVERSION
#undef __SRCVERSION
#endif /*__SRCVERSION */

#define __SRCVERSION(id) \
    __asm__(".section .ident,\"SM\",@progbits,1"); \
    __asm__(".asciz " #id); \
    __asm__(".previous");

#endif /* __QNXNTO__ */

#endif /* __USESRCVERSION */
```

Comment: And in some cases the build can be configured to define the `__SRCVERSION` macro so it either embeds the information in the generated object file or ignores it.